# Start Keyboard animation while transition

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uikeyboard

I have two ViewControllers. When starting my fade transition from VC-A to VC-B I also want the keyboard to show simultaneously. Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyboard can't persist between a navigation even if you set `textF.becomeFirstResponder()` inside `viewDidLoad` of the SecondVC ,  one way is that to fake that navigation and add the second vc as a child with it's x origin = screen.width , then animate it from right to left at the same time you shift FirstVC from x = 0 to x = - screen.width